# Change case of QT Moc file

Tags: c++, qt

I recently refactored old code files from ABCFile.cpp/.h to AbcFile.cpp/.h to match my company's coding standards.  After updating all the references to the old case styling, the code is compiling and running just fine, but looking at qt's automatically generated moc files the casing matches the old style.

What do I need to update qt's references to the updated files?

I have already run a "rebuild all" in Visual Studio, which should run a clean and then fully build deleting and rebuilding moc files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is most likely caused by your Makefile/build procedure.  Try to force it to do a full clean and recompile.  It should delete all your moc files and regenerate them.

Comment: Thanks for the idea.  I had forgotten to mention that I've already run a "rebuild all" in Visual Studio, which I believe deletes and re-mocs all the files.  I'll update my question to reflect

Comment: @Dave if that didn't work, did you try deleting the files manually?

Comment: Good question.  I started working on something else and my code's not compiling :)  When I get to a better point, I'll try that and post an update.  I had considered trying that, but didn't know if deleting the mocs was safe, though I don't know why it wouldn't be.  Thanks for the input.